# NSUserdefaults using xcodebuild

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

xcodebuild has a parameter `-userdefault=value`. How can I use it to set `NSUserDefaults` ? Do I have to specify a file/plist?

Comment: I've never used it but it looks to have `name=value` semantics and it's not clear what user defaults are being changed...

Answer (score 1):

You simply use it as `-name=value` syntax, and it defines the value in the NSUserDefaults (at the `NSArgumentDomain` level) so that you can retrieve it using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"name"]` exactly the same way you usually do.

This is a way to override defaults value from other domains, like the defaults in the application domain (defined by the application preferences's plist).

See [here in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html) for more info (especially Table 1-2) and the paragraph "The Argument Domain".

---

> ### The Argument Domain
>
> The argument domain comprises values set from command- line arguments (if you started the app from the command line) and is identified by the `NSArgumentDomain` constant. Values set from the command line are automatically placed into this domain by the system. To add a value to this domain, specify the preference name on the command line (preceded with a hyphen) and follow it with the corresponding value. For example, the following command launches Xcode and sets the value of its `IndexOnOpen` preference to `NO`:
>
> ```
>     localhost> Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode -IndexOnOpen NO
> ```
>
> Preferences set from the command line temporarily override the established values stored in the user’s defaults database. In the preceding example, setting the `IndexOnOpen` preference to `NO` prevents Xcode from indexing projects automatically, even if the preference is set to `YES` in the user defaults database.